# How to collect the data from about GA and GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have some question about Google Analytics and Google Tag Manager so that I have some values on data layer name  "pageCategory":["highlight-post","brand1","promotions"] I try to categorize the promotion  how can I defined promotion by brand .
The thing that i have done was create custom variable name pageCategory and then I try to use  content grouping on the index level 2 but I'm try to view the result from Google Analytic On behavior -> All page and then select filter by content grouping

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to do more configurations for that custom dimension to be recognized, for example setting that dimension as "pageCategory" but it depends on your setup.

For more information check https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6164990?hl=en